# Program not working on (some) x64 system

Tags: c#, .net

I have recently written a small program and have sent it out into the cruel world. World so cruel that the program seems to be too terrified to run.

I wrote it in C# using Visual Studio 2013. I have not changed any options regarding the System Type (x86 or x64). It uses .NET framework 4.5.2.
(In project build options AnyCPU is selected and Prefer 32-bit is checked)

This is the error that it throws on some machines that are not my own:
[image]

The computer is running Win7 x64. I'm still determining whether and which version of .NET framework is installed.

Could it be due to .NET version incompatibility? E.g. user has version 3.5.
I don't think System Type should be the problem, since it's aimed at AnyCPU.

Ideas?

**EDIT:**
.NET Framework was not an issue. Changing the SystemType explicitly to 32bit makes the program run on both x86 and x64 systems.

This works for me, but might not for a bigger project that needs to run on 64bit code for some reason. You could always distribute two binaries for two system types, but since the feature is here, I don't understand why doesn't it work...

Comment: I wouldn't expect that error message, but yes, you're not going to be able to run an app targeting .NET 4.5.2 on a machine which only has .NET 3.5 on it...

Comment: Is *your* machine x86 or x64? Are you loading any 3rd party libraries?

Comment: It [looks like](http://superuser.com/questions/559703/how-can-i-make-this-32-bit-program-run-on-my-64-bit) that error message might indicate a 16-bit (!) component, which is supported in x86 but not x64 Windows.

Comment: Program isn't all that fancy, not special 16bit stuff. It does come with a dll library (written also by me), but the user has it in the right place. My machine is x64 Win7. I know the app wouldn't run on 3.5, but I don't think it would give this message if that was the case here.

Comment: "World so cruel that the program seems to be too terrified to run."  Your program should implement the `IFearless` interface.